# Getting undefined when trying to access new property created

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have done a lot of research but i keep finding myself in loops or dead ends. I am making a request to a customer API. The result of the request has some coordinates which I am using reverse geocode to get the address of the customer. When i subscribe to `getCustomer()` in my component, I am able to see the **new_address** using `console.log(customer)` however, when trying to drill down to the new property i created `console.log(customer.items[0].new_Address)` returns `undefined`.

Question is why is this happening, and how can it be resolved.

Second Question is, can this be achieved with `MergeMap`

```
getCustomer() {
    return this.http.get('api/customer').pipe(
        map((customer: any) => {
            customer.items.forEach(order => {
                this.getAddress(
                    customer.coordinates.lat,
                    customer.coordinates.long
                ).subscribe((location: any) => {
                    order.new_address = location.results[0]['formatted_address'];
                });
            }, customer.items);
            console.log(orders.items);
            return customer;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            return throwError(error);
        })
    );
}

getAddress(lat, long) {
    return this.http.get(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' +
        lat +
        ',' +
        long +
        '&key=xxx'
    );
}
```

Based on the reply I have received so far, I have updated the code in that I corrected a few syntax errors but there is still an issue. The first returned response or second is not accessible to other operators further down the line. I would like to know how to resolve this.

Here is the returned result from customer API

```
{

    "items": [{
        "customer": "Christopher Wallace",
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 57.500069,
            "long": -0.13453099999999998
        }

    }, {
        "customer": "Amir Khani",
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 58.500069,
            "long": -0.13453099999999998
        }
    }, {
        "customer": "Laporte Fishing",
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 59.500069,
            "long": -0.13453099999999998
        }

    }]
}


//Approach used based on reply
getCustomer() {
    return this.http.get('api/customer').pipe(
      switchMap((customer : any) => this.getAddress(customer.items.coordinates.lat, customer.items.coordinates.long))).pipe(
    // customer is not accessible here, why?
    tap(address => customer.items.forEach(order => order.new_address = address)),
    // customer is not accessible either, why?
    mapTo(customer)
  )
}
```

The idea is to have the structure below which i can subscribe to from my component. My original code above did this but i couldn't get the new_address.

```
{

    "items": [
    {
        "customer": "Christopher Wallace",
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 57.500069,
            "long": -0.13453099999999998
        },
        "new_address": "Abc street 1"
    }, 
    {
        "customer": "Amir Khani",
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 58.500069,
            "long": -0.13453099999999998
        },
        "new_address": "Abc street 2"
    },
    {
        "customer": "Laporte Fishing",
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 59.500069,
            "long": -0.13453099999999998
        },
        "new_address": "Abc street 3"
    }]
}
```

Comment: `customer.items.forEach` will not wait for each `this.getAddress` to resolve. You should instead try using operators such as forkJoin, mergeAll, switchMap or similar if you need to handle an array of requests.

Comment: Are you saying you are setting the `currentAddress` property somewhere?

Comment: @bizzyBob, that should be new_address console.log(customer.items[0].new_address)

Comment: @alexanderStaroselsky, I would like to know how i can use that with my specific scenario as i think its the more appropriate way to do it

Comment: @gables20 You should first try using the operators then if you continue having issues, updating your question with your attempts. I'd try switchMap or mergeMap with forkJoin. Also there are plenty of articles such as https://rangle.io/blog/thinking-in-nested-streams-with-rxjs/ that I'd look at first as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you:

```
  getCustomer() {
    return this.http.getCustomer('api/customer').pipe(
      switchMap(customer => this.getAddress(customer.coordinates).pipe(
        tap(address =>
          customer.items.forEach(order => (order.new_address = address))
        ),
        mapTo(customer)
      )
    ));
  }
```

- `switchMap` will handle subscribing to the inner observable created by `getAddress()`.
- `tap` is for side effects, which is kinda what you were doing by modifying the array elements
- `mapTo` just always returns the provided value

It seemed helpful to have the `getAddress()` return the actual address, so you don't need to dig it out:

```
  getAddress(coordinates: Customer['coordinates']) {
    const { lat, long } = coordinates;
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${long}&key=key}`;

    return this.http.getLocation(url).pipe(
      map(location => location.results[0]['formatted_address'])
    );
  }
```

If you wanted to handle the data in an immutable way, you could return a brand new customer object.  In that case you could just use `map` instead of `tap` and `mapTo`:

```
  getCustomer() {
    return this.http.getCustomer('api/customer').pipe(
      switchMap(customer => this.getAddress(customer.coordinates).pipe(
        map(address => ({
            ...customer,
            items: customer.items.map(order => ({
              ...order, 
              new_address: address
            }))
        }) as Customer)
      ))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain the solution. I am trying to implement it and have a couple of errors and questions. Is there a reason for using two pipes? I removed the second pipe and used a comma as that is flagging an error. Also, "customer" in switchmap is not recognisable in tap or mapTo

Comment: The reason for the second pipe is so that both customer and address are accessible inside. If you remove second pipe, customer is not available because it’s getting mapped to a location. There could be a typo in my code. I’ll check when I’m back to the computer later this evening.

Comment: That makes sense now, yeah there are a few typos. I think you missed a bracket before the second pipe. Still looking to see if i can fix the other errors. Cheers

Comment: Another observation in switchMap line, shouldn't it be customer.items.coordinates.lat?

Comment: wondering why customer or address isn’t accessible despite fixing the pipe issue. Do you think you’d have a chance to suggest improvements today?

Comment: I fixed the typos.  Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-63852364?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that shows no syntax errors :-)

Comment: Cheers. I have looked at your solution and there is no log? Also, i think your array structure is different to mine hence the earlier confusion. But i can fix that if i can get your stackblitz solution to work.

Comment: I updated the question with the returned response from API by the way :)

Comment: The stackblitz is working as intended ;-), but maybe I don't fully understand your problem.  I updated the SB to display info in the template.  Hopefully that helps.  If not, please create a new SB that illustrates your problem.  It will be much easier to help :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for editing that. I updated the question with json response as well. I feel like if i create a new question, it would be considered duplicate. Any chance you could update your answer based on this? cheers